# Angular attributes on directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I don't understand what the attribute is doing in this case:

```
<div my-custom-directive="what does this do?"></div>
```

A real world example:

```
 <div class="grid" ui-grid="gridOptionsSimple"> </div>
```

It isn't to pass in attributes to the linking function because you might do this like this:

```
<div my-custom-attribute="what does this do?" extra-attribute="123"></div>
```

It looks like it creates a property on the scope. But that's as far as I've got. Sorry. Quite a beginner question.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: It does add a very specific attribute to the link function.  Other required two-way bindings still need to be specified with other attributes.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you wanted to understand?

Comment: I didn't either. I was confused. However the accepted answer answered the question which I could not even properly formulate which should probably get some kind of a bonus point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `ui-grid="gridOptionsSimple"` it's passing along the value of `gridOptionsSimple` on the parent scope into UI-Grid's isolate scope.

If you check out the source for the ui-grid directive (here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/v3.0.0-rc.22/src/js/core/directives/ui-grid.js#L196) you'll see that the directive is specifying that the `uiGrid` ("ui-"grid in snake-case) scope property is bound to the `uiGrid` attribute ('=' is just short for '=uiGrid').

```js
return {
  templateUrl: 'ui-grid/ui-grid',
  scope: {
    uiGrid: '='
  },
  replace: true,
  transclude: true,
  ...
};
```

This allows to the grid to get all the options and data references into its own scope without dirtying and parent controller scope.

Comment: Thanks c0bra. The part that was eluding me is explained by your "= is just short for =uiGrid". This is a special case. If the isolate scope property name is the same as the attribute name you can just use "=". This short-cut means that if your isolate scope property has the same name as the directive you don't need any other attributes and cas just use '='. I had to do a fiddle to work it out. http://jsfiddle.net/justinwyllie/0haj72ag/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I think your question is about:

```
var app = angular.module('demo',[]);

app.directive('SampleQuilt', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{ extraAttribute: "@", someText: "@"  }
            };
  });
```

By adding **scope** to the directive we create an "*isolated scope*". With this approach **scope** can capture attributes in 3 ways:

1. **`@`** Captures the attribute value from the DOM as string value.
2. **`=`** Evaluates the attribute as property of the parent scope.
3. **`&`** Evaluates the attribute as method of the parent scope.

You can read more about it here:

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/

Regarding your **html**:

- Cases (camel case or pascal case) means dash in angular directives so `sampleText` needs to be used as `sample-text` in the html.

Comment: Ok you were faster ;) Maybe add an example link function to show how to access those things in the scope and explain the difference between `scope` and `attrs`.